# Getting problem while getting group id of current logged in user

Tags: extension, groups, core

I am trying to get a group id of currently logged in user

`function search_civicrm_preProcess($formName, &$form) {
    $getContactId = (int) CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->getLoggedInContactID();
    $query = "select 'group_id' from 'civicrm_group_contact' where contact_id ='.$getContactId'";
$dao1 =&  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery( $query, CRM_Core_DAO::$_nullArray );

}`

Answer (score 2):

I would use api to find groups of logged in user

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', [
  'return' => ["group"],
  'id' => 'user_contact_id',
]);

or 

$result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'getsingle', [
  'return' => ["group_id"],
  'contact_id' => 'user_contact_id',
]);
```

HTH

Pradeep